# Where does the washer go when replacing this toilet seat?

Tags: toilet

[image]

I am replacing the seat on a RAK Flora toilet . The replacement parts have a bolt, to go down thru the porcelain, then a plastic wing nut, metal washer and another plastic bit which just slides along the bolt. My question is, what order do I put those 3 onto the bolt? Should the washer go against the porcelain or between the 2 plastic bits?.

Comment: Did the seat come with instructions? What do they say?

Comment: [RAK Infinity Seat](http://www.rakbathware.com.au/images/brochures/1-infintiy_seat_installation_instructions.pdf) This is the only seat shown that has the same style hinge point. 
The above replacement differs quite a bit.

Comment: There were no instructions and the RAK site doesn't have the exact same seat, the replacement is a 'new' version. I think I'll just call a plumber/ builder to install it. thanks!